# iOS QuickLook framework alternative

Tags: objective-c, ios, frameworks, quicklook

I'm developing client for http://sparkleshare.org, OSS Dropbox alternative. For previewing of files I'm using QuickLook framework, but it seems it previews only PDF (maybe I do something wrong).
What uses iOS dropbox client for previewing files? Is any QuickLook alternatives? Should I use it?

Comment: QuickLook handles a half-dozen or so file types, not just PDF.

Comment: There are no quick look alternatives.  If you want to be able to read all those formats, you've got to get down and dirty.